# Convert a Community Theme to an Enterprise Theme

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have currently purchased a Magento theme and plugged it into my EE installation. The theme works fine but EE specific features like Banners/Widgets and Gift Cards are not displaying or working properly. What would I need to do to convert this theme written for CE into a EE theme that supports all EE features? Is it as easy as copying the missing Enterprise Theme items for /layout/ and /template/ into the new theme or is there some underlying programming differences int he Enterprise Theme that I would need to add/change?

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you would be to copy the template and layout files from EE base/default theme into your new theme's folder and just edit them where necessary. This shouldn't take too long, it will mostly be CSS but you will find you need slight changes in the template files. Good luck!